# Animating the value of a TextBlock between two values until an action completes

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8, storyboard

I was wondering whether it's possible to have an animation whereby the Text value of a TextBlock switches between two values. The FontFamily for the TextBlock is an icon font and so  what I'm aiming to pull off is essentially an animated icon.

For example:

```
                        <StackPanel
                        x:Name="PART_LayoutRoot">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Storyboard 
                                x:Name="PART_Animation">
                                <<STRING>Animation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="progressBarIcon"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text"
                                    From="hi" To="bye" Duration="0:0:1"
                                    AutoReverse="True"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <TextBlock 
                            x:Name="progressBarIcon"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Does an animation type exists that will enable me to achieve what I'm after? If not, is there any other way to do so without using a storyboard animation? I'm planning to use this animation until a certain action completes i.e. a custom busy indicator.

Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating string properties is not possible this way for two reasons - there is no clear way how a string animation should look, and also the value of the `Text` property would be unclear/invalid during the animation.

To achieve the result you want, you will need to create two `TextBlocks`, one with full `Opacity="1"` and one with `Opacity="0"` and then animate these opacities - one to fade out, one to fade in - this is possible normally with the `DoubleAnimation` so you will not run into any issues here.

Comment: Smart, but how do I ensure the TextBlocks are on top of each other so that when one fades out, the one underneath it fades in and vice-versa? This is to ensure that it's a fluid animation.

Comment: You can enter both animations in one storyboard and they will be both in sync. This is not very resource-expensive and will fast and fluid :-) .

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't more clear. What you've suggested results in one TextBlock being above the other. 

i.e. 

1
0

That is, they have unique positions on the screen but only one shows at a time. 

I'd like for it to be:

1

or

0

That is, when 1 is visible for it to show, and when 0 is visible it shows where 1 was and not in a different position. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Well, you can place both in a Grid or other container and then just set both to VerticalAlignment="Center" and HorizontalAlignment="Center" to center them both in the grid. They will be exactly on top of each other this way.

Comment: Happy to see it helped :-) !